# HTML programming features not enabled in .php files in VS Code

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

There are few questions on the SO which talks about some or another HTML feature is not working when the file is stored as `.php` file. I researched on this and I tried the following.

Try 1

```
//Only PHP features work.
"files.associations": {
    "*.php":["html", "php"]
}
```

Try 2

```
//Only HTML Features work.
"files.associations": {
    "*.php":"html"
}
```

Try 3

```
Change the language in the footer of VS Code.
```

I am using latest version `v1.18.1` `x64 bit` of Visual Studio Code.

> Detail of Issue

When detected language is PHP, the code completion of PHP works. When language changed to HTML, the closing tags highlighting, HTML attributes suggestions works perfectly.

Comment: Don't know if this is related to the bug https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/670

Comment: So, you've noticed something not working in your IDE. You did some research and found questions here on SO which confirmed this. What is your actual _question_ here and how does it differ from the existing ones?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson was hoping if someone was able to figure out the solution to this issue.

Comment: For future reference, any post here needs to include an actual question. This is more of a "how to reproduce a software bug", which is great when you're creating an error ticket or a issue on a git repo. Btw, the github issue you linked to is pretty spot on.

Comment: Have you tried "PHP Intelliphense" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client extension?  "HTML request forwarding allowing for a full HTML/Javascript/CSS/PHP development experience."